# CSS - Vertically centering

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I cannot seem to comprehend what's going on here:

I want to vertically center an iframe & another div, both of which will sit alongside each other horizontally.

What I have done is that I have placed the above two (iframe and div) inside another div called 'iframe_r_container' and positioned it as absolute & display set as table.

HTML:

```
<body id="container">

    <div id="menu_bars">
        <div id="main_bar">
            <ul>
                <li class="maintabs"><a href="#">a</a></li><li class="maintabs"><a href="#">b</a></li><li class="maintabs"><a href="#">c</a>
                </li><li class="maintabs"><a href="#">d</a></li>
            </ul>           
        </div>  

        <div id="filemenu">
            <ul>
                <li class="filetabs"><a href="#">File</a></li><li class="filetabs"><a href="#">Edit</a></li><li class="filetabs"><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="iframe_r_container">
        <iframe id="iframing" src="mannequin.html" frameborder="0" ></iframe>

        <div id="right_container">
            <div id="user_credit">
                <h1><a href="#">Username</a></h1><br />
                 has <span id="credits">000</span> credits.
            </div>

            <div> <button id="template_button"><img src="images/Coutallure-WebApp/template_button.png" /><span>Templates</span></button> </div>

    <!-- contains the jquery widget for displaying the features, i.e. buttons, zips etc -->
            <div id="features_container">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  </body></html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/*  RESETS  */
html, body, div, span,
object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5,
h6,  p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr,
address, cite, code, del, dfn, em,
img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong,
sub, sup, var, b, i,  dl, dt, dd, ol,
ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead,
tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas,
details, figure, figcaption, hgroup,
menu, footer, header, nav, section,
summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, 'Myriad Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: rgba(34,34,34,1);
}
a img {border: 0;} /* END OF RESET */

#container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative;
}

#menu_bars {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* START OF MAIN BAR */
#main_bar ul {
    float: left;
    width: 630px;
    height: 48px;
}
```

.......... it goes on and on AND BELOW IS THE PROBLEM AREA I THINK

```
/* START OF IFRAME_R_CONTAINER */
#iframe_r_container {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    top: 48px;
    bottom: 38px;
    width: 960px;
}

/* START OF IFRAME */
#iframing {
    display: table-column;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
/* END OF IFRAME */


/* START OF RIGHT CONTAINER */
#right_container {
display: table-column;
    width: 113px;
    margin: 20px;
}

#user_credit {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: lowercase; 
    line-height: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#user_credit h1 a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#template_button {
    width: 130px;
    height: 28px;
    background: rgba(238,238,238,0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#template_button img {
    margin: 3px 6px 4px 0px;
}

#template_button span {
    vertical-align: 11px;
}

#feature_container {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* END OF RIGHT CONTAINER */
/*END OF IFRAME_R_CONTAINER */
```

Comment: can you give a screenshot of what it looks like?

Comment: My apologies, this is such a ridiculously put question with far too much info. Am rewriting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into this: - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

I have never heard of table-column.